# Can I wire a ceiling fan light with 2 wall switches adding a dimmer switch for the light and control fan speed with remote that came with fan?

Tags: electrical

Can I wire a ceiling fan/light with 2 wall switches adding a dimmer switch for the light and still control the fan speed with the remote that came with fan?

Comment: Is the fan and light working now with the switches and remote?

Comment: Do you have instructions or a wiring guide for the fan?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Answer (score 2):

Most fan remotes are designed to take constant power from one wall switch (that will always be switched on) and control the light and fan with the remote.  If installed as usual, one switch would stay on all the time, the other switch would not be used, and the remote would control the lights and fan.  You can see a wiring diagram for that in [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/47125/how-do-i-install-a-ceiling-fan-remote).  "AC Power In" is power from the standard wall switch and the other connections are between the remote and the fan.

[image: remote wiring]

The specifics of your remote might differ, but to do what you want, you will need to wire one switch to the "hot" wire on the remote and then wire the dimmer switch to the "light" wire on the fan.  The wire from the remote that should be connected to the lights will need to be capped off, and of course the fan wire should connect to the fan wire on the ceiling fan.

With this setup, the remote will not be able to control the light.  It will only control the fan.

Several fan remotes have dimmers for the lights included, so you can probably get what you want by choosing the correct remote control module and using the remote for everything.  You have to choose between using the remote for the light or a wired dimmer.  You can't have both.

Comment: You want to make sure that, whatever you do, you don't put the fan on the lighting dimmer. You can burn out the dimmer and/or the fan, and possibly start a fire.