# Can I wire a ceiling fan light with 1 wall switch, adding a dimmer switch for the light and control fan speed with remote that came with fan?

Tags: wiring, dimmer-switch, fans

[This is my scenario](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/235272/can-i-wire-a-ceiling-fan-light-with-2-wall-switches-adding-a-dimmer-switch-for-t), except I only have one switch in 2 gang wall plates that goes up to the ceiling fan. The other switch goes to the half switched outlet.

The red wire is the switched hot in the ceiling that powers my fan light (on/off only) directly bypassing the remote light receiver (capped blue wire). The black unswitched wire in ceiling powers the fan and is not affected by the switch. Wanted to use a dimmer switch instead of using a remote to dim lights without affecting the fan motor.  Will use remote with fan speed.

Would I connect the switch wires (currently red and black) to the dimmer switch?

Additional clarification. Currently in ceiling power there are two hot wires- one is black (unswitched) and red (switches) along with white and ground. I have the hunter fan currently set up so that the light is controlled (on/off) by switch using red wire (wired directly to ceiling fan blue and recieiver blue capped). Black unswitched hot wire is connected to receiver so that remote controls fan motor speed separately. I just wanted to change the current switch to a dimmer switch for fan light only ( not messing with fan motor). All White wires and ground are pigtailed to each respective color. I know from other discussions the fan speed/motor should be left alone when it’s a remote fan

Comment: There's not much information in the linked post. Please provide all information _here_, so we don't all have to jump around the internet to understand you.

Comment: It's not clear how many wires are in your cable. Please revise to clarify that. In the U.S., a red wire is usually a _third_ conductor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch you currently have that works the fan's light would just be replaced with a dimmer.

The dimmer will not affect the fan, if the fan is powered by "The black unswitched wire in the ceiling."

Just be sure the bulb or Led light you have on the fan is dimmable and the dimmer and light are compatible.